# Turn off HUD/UI in SSBU

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I'd like to turn off the UI elements of a match in Super Smash Bros Ultimate to record video.  Is there a way to turn off these elements (specifically the character icon, damage %, Stock count, and character name)?  The only element I've found to turn off is the minimap for when players go off-screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do know it's possible to turn off damage % through the Rule Settings by setting "Show Damage" to "Off" in the Advanced section.
However, I don't see any way to turn off the other elements you've mentioned.

It does seem like you can turn off (at least some of) the UI when converting a replay into a video, according to [the wiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Replay#Video_rendering), so that might be your best bet.

Quote from the linked wiki page:

> In Super Smash Bros. Ultimate, replays can be converted to video files, which will be saved to the Nintendo Switch system's SD card under Nintendo/Album/Extra. When converting a replay, the user can choose whether to hide display elements like the damage meters, whether to mute the background music and/or sound effects, and whether to use high or normal video quality.